# hvplot heatmap ordering axis

Tags: holoviews, pyviz, hvplot

Question is, can I order the axis of a heatmap in hvplot?

I have the following code:

```
df['col_1'] = df.col_1.astype(int).astype('category')
df['col_2'] = df.col_1.astype(int)


heatmap = df.hvplot.heatmap('col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 
reduce_function=np.median)

heatmap
```

But when I run it, the col_1 and col_2 are in random orders

If I do a Pandas groupby:

```
df.groupby(['col_1', 'col_2]).col_3.median().unstack()
```

I get the table I want with the correct sorting of col_1 and col_2 as axis of the heatmap. My previous code then passed this dataframe to seaborn.heatmap()

Is there a way to force the ordering in hvplot?

Ben

Comment: See https://github.com/pyviz/hvplot/issues/122